# SendKeys not working/being blocked in my c# application

Tags: c#, if-statement, sendkeys

I have an **if** statement in my code which contains a `shutdownProcess()` method (which uses many, many `SendKeys.Send` calls) that works perfectly fine when used alone in the **if** statement:

```
if (waitForRegressionTestToComplete.WaitOne(10*60*1000))
            {
                shutdownProcess();
            }
```

As I said, this works exactly how I want it to. The `SendKeys.Send` works as it should, and the process shuts down. However, when I add other items into the if statement, the code enters `shutdownProcess()` and "sends the keys," but with absolutely no result. The first two keys sent in the method are ALT+TAB x2 in order to regain focus in case it was lost:

```
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
```

Here is the **if** statement after I have added new items, which causes the problem:

```
if (waitForRegressionTestToComplete.WaitOne(10*60*1000))
            {
                shutdownProcess();

                bool processIsStillRunning = true;

                while (processIsStillRunning)
                {
                    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

                    processIsStillRunning = false;
                    foreach (Process process in processlist)
                    {
                        if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Process"))
                        {
                            processIsStillRunning = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The thread also seems to freeze after it has "sent" all of the keys, since it is waiting for the process to exit--to no avail.
Thanks in advance for your help. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Have you tried using Sendkeys.SendWait?

Comment: I have not. Let me try implementing that really quick. The description looks like it could work. . .

Answer (score 0):

As **@Jordy** said, `SendKeys.SendWait` was the solution to the problem. This waits for the input to be processed, thus avoiding anything else being done before the keystroke's action takes place.

`SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");` instead of `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");`